# How Does CodeIgniter Verify Session Data?

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, cookies, codeigniter-2

There is a similar question already asked but none provided the right answer so I will go a bit more in depth to make sure we understand. PHP sessions store a server-side session ID that will be compared to that which is saved in the cookie on the client side but CodeIgniter does not seem to store the session ID server side, if so, how does it know the cookie grabbed from the client is valid and has not been tampered with?

I looked through CodeIgniter's functions in the session library and it does not seem to store the session ID anywhere, couldn't I just create my own cookie to resemble CodeIgniter's and go through the page's security?
All answers appreciated good day to everybody.

Comment: Are u asking about 2.* or 3.0 ? Cuz 3.0 was completely changed to better since 2.* was just doing it wrong when it came to sessions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Excellent question.

CodeIgniter stores the **[Serialized](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/2.1-stable/system/libraries/Session.php#L167-L168)** value of session data in the cookie, including `session_id`, `ip_address`, `user_agent`, `last_activity`.

> how does it know the cookie grabbed from the client is valid and has
>   not been tampered with?

In order to validate the session, and improve the security, CodeIgniter provides a [set of configs](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/2.1-stable/application/config/config.php#L247-L255) allows you to check the client `user agent` and/or `IP address` as well.

```php
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_ip']        = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
```

- `sess_encrypt_cookie` Lets you **encrypt** the Serialized session before being stored in the cookie.
- `sess_match_ip` **Matches** the IP of the client when reading the session data.
- `sess_match_useragent` **Matches** the User Agent when reading the session data.

> couldn't I just create my own cookie to resemble CodeIgniter's and go
>   through the page's security?

First, if you enable the `sess_encrypt_cookie` config, (While you've set an [encryption key](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/2.1-stable/application/config/config.php#L218-L227) in your config.php file) CodeIgniter will encrypt the serialized session data using your own encryption key and store the encrypted data in the cookie.

Hence, the client couldn't change the variables.

For the other two configs, by enabling them, CodeIgniter tries to validate the **user agent** and/or **IP address** of the client by comparing to Session data. And **if they don't match**, [CI will removes the entire Session](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/2.1-stable/system/libraries/Session.php#L184-L196).

### Storing session into Database

By using this feature, CodeIgniter stores all the above Session data **including** the `user_data` into the database. And it won't store the `user_data` in the cookie any more.

This would fix the cookie storage limit issue (which you can store up to 4KB in the cookie) and protect the `user_data` info from being tampered.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't vote up I can't yet. Terrific answer and very thorough. Hopefully this will help somebody, as it did me, in understanding how to work better with the sessions in CodeIgniter since as you pointed out, the default values are not secure. Thank you for your excellent answer.

Comment: @stacker My pleasure, don't mention it :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is not checking if you use only cookie, the cookie work as storage to store your session between browser and php
The parameter `$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';` indicate the name of the cookie and its just a random value, so you can do whatever you want with the value even modify.

But if you set  `$config['sess_encrypt_cookie'] = TRUE;` its encrypt your cookie using `$config['encryption_key'] = 'XYZ';` that's make it secure, and to manipulate the cookie you have to decrypt/encrypte the cookie using same encryption key.

So the best practice is use database session to store your session in database and cookie work as a session id, if you change the value you will lose your session. Now choice is your.